# Problem while coding in mplab x ide for pic18f

Tags: c, compiler-errors, pic18, mplab-c18

I am using pic18f and coding on mplab v ide. While compiling the code it's showing that 'RD3' is depricated. What should be the solution to it.

Comment: Hi @shashisingh. You shuld have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic to ask a well received question. We cannot give you a solution based on guessing. You need to provide enough information on the issue such as the exact IDE error text, exact model of PIC i.e. PIC18F2550, the piece of code which causes the issue and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) whenever possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.